# Will using Product Ontology’s "Real_estate" type help SEO?

Tags: seo, structured-data, productontology.org

How advisable is this type of structured data to be used?

http://www.productontology.org/doc/Real_estate

Comment: How would you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Using microdata doesn't help rankings.  At best it lets Google display your site with enhancements in the search results.

Google lists the microdata that they use in their search gallery:  https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings   I don't see any way they treat real estate specially listed there.

There is currently no reason to use real estate microdata from an SEO standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It won't help your rankings directly, but as Stephen Ostermiller points out, at best it will let Google display your site with enhancements in the SERPs.

Now, the indirect benefit will come from being more "attractive" in the search results, which will bring you a better CTR, and if you can retain your visitors for a decent time, then this will send a positive signal to Google that your site delivers the answers and solutions the users are looking for.

Finally, you will be getting more traffic thanks to these enhancements and if your copy is spot on, and that means more possible sales and clients.

Comment: Except that to my knowledge Google doesn't use real estate schema to make anything look better in the search results.  Do you know of something they use it for?